# Pick path in Tag Helper attribute

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

Lets say I want to create a custom ImageTagHelper, which loads the image name from a database field and generates an IMG. As there is only the name coming from the db, you have to specify a folder, where all images exist.

The Tag Helper looks like:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("image", Attributes = ForAttributeName, TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
    public class ImageTagHelper : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelper
    {
        public ImageTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator)
        {
        }

        public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Path to picture
        /// </summary>
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Extension
        /// </summary>
        public string Extension { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Alt text
        /// </summary>
        public string Alt { get; set; }


        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.TagName = "img";
            output.TagMode = TagMode.SelfClosing;

            var src = ImagePath + For.ModelExplorer.Model + "." + Extension;
            output.Attributes.Add("src", src);
            output.Attributes.Add("alt", Alt);
        }



    }
```

In ASP.NET Razor i would write:

```
<image asp-for="Id" image-path="~/images/" alt="No picture" extension="png"/>
```

How can I pick a path in wwwroot, when typing text in the `image-path-attribute`? I looked in [GitHub ImageTagHelper source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/ImageTagHelper.cs/), but the `src` attribute is also defined as string. Is there something magic happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK that is the magic of visual studio tooling for HTML attributes. It has nothing to do with tag helpers or aspnet core.

Comment: Note, that there's an open issue on Razor to provide a marker attribute on TagHelpers that VS could then consume to provide proper IntelliSense: https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/429